# Resampling a timeseries

Tags: time-series, bootstrap, resampling

I have a list of stock returns (say computed from the historical data) and would like to resample the historical return distribution. Naively doing bootstrapping means the samples are iid. I'm particularly interested in correlation between consecutive returns (a large return should be more likely to be followed by a large return of either sign)

Is there any standard way we can do this? I had a stab of this myself -

0. Assume the return of the day t is dependent on t-1
1. Break the return into (arbitary) buckets.
2. Estimate the probability day t return is belongs to a certain bucket, based on which bucket t-1 is from.
3. For every t, first sample which bucket it belongs to conditional t-1 using estimated probability then pick a sample from this bucket uniformly.

Is there any reference someone suggests where is such techniques are discussed. Thanks!

Comment: Please [research this on our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=time+series+bootstrap*).  We have *many* threads about bootstrapping time series.

Answer (score 1):

These returns are not *iid*, because:

- they aren't identically distributed (have different variances, even if having the same absolute or scaled mean),
- nor independent (the latter because their variances sort of depend on each other).

Instead of resampling, I would suggest that you take a look at [autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity) models (there are many of them).

Comment: ARCH models have some assumption of normality, which is  not entirely suitable here.